# Сохранить результаты в один файл \ Поиск

Tags: delphi

**Задание:** В папке имеется список файлов. Нужно **вытащить строки**, по ключевому слову - '**Zadaniye**' из **каждого файла**, что в папке и **записать эти строки** в один файл (**Save.txt**).

**Проблема, у меня, в следующем:** Получается, что результаты - записываются в разные файлы, а нужно в один.

**Пример, для уточнения:**

В папке есть файлы **1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt**. Программа ищет все строки, где есть слово **Zadaniye**, в этих файлах и:

**Записывает результат вот так:**

```
Save_1.txt
Save_2.txt
Save_3.txt
```

**А нужно, все найденные результаты, со всех файлов - записать в один файл. То есть:**

```
Save.txt
```

**Где я допустила ошибку ? Делаю вот та, но у меня:**

```
// ищем все файлы в папке
procedure findfile2(dir, path: string; var file_list: TStringList);
var
  SR: TSearchRec;
  FindRes: Integer;
begin
  FindRes := FindFirst(dir + path, faAnyFile - faDirectory, SR);
  while FindRes = 0 do
  begin
    file_list.Add(dir + SR.name);
    FindRes := FindNext(SR);
  end;
  FindClose(SR);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  fall, f1: TextFile;
  S: string;
  i: Integer;
  file_list: TStringList;
  flname1, flname2: string;
  p: string;
begin

  file_list:=TStringList.Create;
  // расширение файлов
  p:='*' + ExtractFileExt(flname);
  // Путь к папке
  findfile2('C:\Users\Tatyana\Desktop\Новая папка\T'+'\',p,file_list);

   //Делаем проход по файлам
   for i:=0 to file_list.Count-1 do begin

    flname1:=file_list.Strings[i];
    flname2:=ExtractFileDir(flname1)+'\'+'Save_'+extractfilename(flname1);

    // Открываем каждый файл в цикле
    AssignFile(fall, flname1);
    reset(f1);
    // Записываем результат
    AssignFile(f1, flname2);
    rewrite(f1);


  // работаем по строкам в файле
  while not Eof(fall) do
  begin
    // читаем строку
    ReadLn(fall, S);
    if (PosEx('Zadaniye', S) > 0) then
      writeln(f1, S);
  end;

  CloseFile(fall);
  CloseFile(f1);
end;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вынесите

```
 // Записываем результат
  AssignFile(f1, 'Save.txt');
  rewrite(f1);
```

и

```
  CloseFile(f1);
```

за цикл.

Comment: Файл открыли - цикл начался - строки пишем, пишем, пишем - цикл кончился - файл закрыли

Comment: Все, разобралась и сделала по вашим рекомендациям. Все работает...